# Arithmetic in python, can't figure out simple basic operations

Tags: python, math

I am doing some very basic excersizes in python. I'm using the hard way to learn python book, which in excersize 3 have a expression I should understand.

3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6, is coming out as 7.

For me, the answer is 6.

6 - 5 + 0 - 1 / 4 + 6

1 - 1 / 4 + 6

6.

This is clearly wrong, but can anyone help me with priorty in mathematics etcetera? I seem to have forgotten everything if it's not inside a parenthesis!

EDIT: Thank you very much for the response. I've clearly learned something about the very basic stuff, which I think is important before moving on! My order of operations was definately way off!

Answer (score 5):

4 % 2 = 0 because the remainder of 4 / 2 is 0

1 / 4 is also 0 because it is doing integer division and .25 is floored to 0.

Comment: Python doesn't round here, it *floors*.  For example `3 / 4` is `0` not `1`

Answer (score 3):

If we look at the [rules for Operator precedence in Python](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary) we can see that:

```
3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6
```

is being treated as:

```
3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + (4 % 2) - (1 / 4) + 6
```

(For the arithmetic operators this is the same order as the [standard order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) in mathematics.)

Now `4 % 2` is `0` since the remainder when dividing 4 by 2 is 0.  `1 / 4` is also `0` as Python will return a value of the same type as the operands and 0.25 when "floored" is 0.

So I think your mistake is applying the `/` to the whole expression to the left.  In fact as `/` has a higher precedence than `-` the division evaluated is `1 / 4`.

Answer (score 2):

`1/4` rounds down (or floors) to `0` since 1 and 4 are integers.
Therefore `1-0+6 = 7`

Comment: It doesn't "round" - that is just how integer division evaluates in python.

Comment: Python doesn't round here, it *floors*.  For example `3 / 4` is `0` not `1`

Comment: Okay, "In Python `1/4` rounds down to ... "

Comment: @DaveWebb 'rounding off' includes both flooring and ceiling but i agree, I should have said rounds down or floors

Comment: @vikki: "I should have said"... What makes sense is to actually edit your answer rather than apologize.

Answer (score 2):

See the table of operator precedences in Python.

http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think that python should evaluate everything to the left of a `/` operator before dividing by the first token to the right. That would be an odd evaluation order by any measure.

As always with programming: if you have a complex expression with infix operators, use brackets to force the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

Priority is for division and multiplication, if you don't use brackets!

In this way: 1-1/4+6=7  because 1/4, working with integer, is = 0

Answer (score 1):

In Python3.x it'd be 6.75 b/c 1/4 = 0.25 (true division). However, in Python 2.x 1/4 = 0 (convert to the most generic type of the arguments used, that is int in given case). Therefore, if it'd be 1. / 4 or 1 / 4. then in Python2.x you'd get 0.25 and the result would be 6.75

Answer (score 0):

operands are integer, so 1/4 integer dividing = 0

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mathematics you should have a look at the operators:

`a%b` is a modular b, which in case of a=4 and b=2 yields 0 (ok, thanks mathematics ;) )

`1/4`: here it's important to take into account that 1 and 4 are integers. So the result will also be an integer, i.e. 0.25 becomes 0.

That's why you end up with

```
  3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6
= 3 + 2 + 1 - 5 +   0   -   0   + 6
=                                 7
```

For operators in python have a look at [the python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6
```

The order of precedence for this is multiplication and division evaluated left to right and then addition and subtraction. So..

```
3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + (4 % 2) - (1 / 4) + 6
```

The ones inside the parentheses are evaluated first because of order of operations. Because you only have integers present (and not a float which would allow the value 0.25), 1/4 will floor to 0 because of python.

```
3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 0 - 0 + 6
```

Afterwards, when you evaluate from left to right for addition/subtraction, you are left with:

```
6 - 5 + 6  => 1 + 6 => 7
```

Remember that division and multiplication are evaluated before addition and subtraction. For more information, [Order of Operations - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)